# Who are the other three superheroes in Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

When Bruce Wayne sends an email to Wonder Woman, she sees three other superhero videos in it. Who are they? Do they appear in any other superhero movies?

Comment: The flash video is in suicide squad... The shoplifter is boomerang

Comment: @user40679 No, it's not. And no, that was not Captain Boomerang. Totally different incident, as also evidence by Flash not actually wearing his costume in the video, while he does in *Suicide Squad*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The files even had there superhero logos:

[image: DCEU version of Wonder Woman, Cyborg, Flash and Aquaman's logos]

<sub>Wonder Woman, Cyborg, Flash and Aquaman from left to right order.</sub>

- [Victor Stone/Cyborg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_(comics)) (played by Ray Fisher): A boy whose partial remaining body got attached to a mother box to make him into cyborg.

  [image: Silas Stone describing the experiments being conducted on his own son Victor (aka Cyborg)]

  On the top right there is partial remaining body of  Victor Stone and on the right bottom is the [Mother Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box) which is responsible in his creation in the comics and in [animated film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War).
- [Arthur Curry/Aquaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman) (played by Jason Momoa): The man under the sea.

  [image: Aquaman stabbing an underwater camera]
- [Barry Allen/The Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Barry_Allen)) (played by Ezra Miller): Man in supermarket stopping the thief.

  [image: black and white image of Flash caught on supermarket camera]

All three have been scheduled for their respective standalone films:

- [*Aquaman* (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe#The_Flash_.282018.29)
- [*Cyborg* (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe#Cyborg_.282020.29).
- and [*Flashpoint* (TBD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe#Flashpoint)

They will also  appear in [*Justice League* (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(film)) and [Untitled *Justice League* sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe#Untitled_Justice_League_sequel)

Comment: No more Affleck and no Cavill in DCEU :-( I don't know what plans there may be after Aquaman, Shazam! and Wonder Woman 2

Comment: @m1gp0z Aquaman was awesome so it’s going in right direction